# Draw the polyline along the path of the map in openlayer3

Tags: service, openlayers-3, polyline, direction

I following code how to draw the polyline along path of the map, know for the point present in the map will just give the straight line how to get along the path of the lanes

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Rotation example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="width:80%; height:80%; position:fixed; border: 1px solid;" id="map"></div>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script>

        var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString([
            [103.986083,  1.350349],
            [103.985097, 1.349067]
        ]);
        lineString.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

        var lineLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: [new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: lineString,
                    name: 'Line'
                })]
            }),
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: [255, 255, 0, 0.5],
                    width: 10
                })
            })
        });

        var view = new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([103.986908, 1.353199], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 18,
            rotation: 68*Math.PI/180
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),
                lineLayer
            ],
            target: 'map',
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
            }),
            view: view
        });



    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Is there any direction service provided by openlayer3 please point to sample to accomplish it

Answer (score 0):

If you have coordinates along the lanes you can use [MultiLineString](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.1/apidoc/ol.geom.MultiLineString.html) instead of LineString.

Comment: can u please point to some demo or sample code which will help to do this

Comment: i am trying like this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174876/how-to-draw-coordinates-along-the-lanes-using-multilinestring-instead-of-linestr    but the polylines are not displayed can u please say what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a routing service for such action. You may setup your own service or you may use any online available. [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) you can find a list of free online routers and decide which one best feet to your needs.
Once you get your root polyline out of the selected service you can then decode (if encoded) and draw your line within your ol3 map.
Also cosider, depending on the service you are going to use, that ol3 offers a class  for reading and writing data in the Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format which is described [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.0/apidoc/ol.format.Polyline.html)

Comment: i am trying like this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174876/how-to-draw-coordinates-along-the-lanes-using-multilinestring-instead-of-linestr    but the polylines are not displayed can u please say what is wrong

Comment: I have answered to the question you provide. maybe it helps your case

Comment: please provide specific example where i can draw polylines using any one of the direction service for example(OSRM) I am really confused how to integrate with  the existing application please provide one method or a function which can help me to do it